# Pointer error when deleting duplicates in a Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I want to delete all duplicates from a linked list. I know there is an exact program on GeeksForGeeks which is very similar to mine and I could use that, but I want to understand why mine is not working.

Code:

```
class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
 
};

void removeDuplicatesAlpha(Node* start)
{
    Node* ptr1 = start;
    Node* ptr2 = NULL;
    Node* dup = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    /* Pick elements one by one */
    while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr2 = ptr1->next;
        //0 1 2 3 4
        /* Compare the picked element with rest
           of the elements */
        while (ptr2 != NULL && ptr2->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << i;
            i++;

            /* If duplicate then delete it */
            if (ptr1->data == ptr2->data)
            {
                /* sequence of steps is important here */
                dup = ptr2;
                ptr2 = ptr2->next;
                delete(dup);
            }
            else /* This is tricky */
                ptr2 = ptr2->next;
        }
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL;

    push(&head, 3);
    push(&head, 3);
    push(&head, 20);
    push(&head, 14);
    push(&head, 9);
    push(&head, 20);
    push(&head, 20);

    printList(head);

    //removeDuplicates(head);
    removeDuplicatesAlpha(head);

    printList(head);

    deleteList(&head);

    return 0;
}
```

The last i printed is 4.

This is the error: Exception thrown: read access violation.
**ptr2** was 0xDDDDDDDD.

I'm so sorry if this is a dumb question but I just started working with Data Structures in C++.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. For this kind of programs, it also helps if you step through it with a debugger or create a diagram of your data structures. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` your  debugger is trying to tell you something. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations) `0xDDDDDDDD` means freed heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
            dup = ptr2;
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            delete(dup);
```

This deletes one of the `Node`s.

If you review your what's in your `Node` class, you will see that each `Node` has a `next` pointer, that links to the next node in the list.

The above code deletes the actual `Node`, but it does nothing, whatsoever, to any of the `next` pointers in the linked list. The previous `Node` in the linked list: it's `next` is still pointing to this `Node`. You just `delete`d this `Node`. It no longer exists. Attempting to use and dereference the previous `Node`'s `next`, that was pointing to the `delete`d `Node` becomes undefined behavior. This must be the reason for your crash.

You will need to update your logic in order to update the `next` pointers in your linked list accordingly.

Comment: If the code is otherwise correct, the only thing that needs fixing, is to change ```ptr2 = ptr2->next``` to ```ptr1 = ptr2->next```. That way you make the previous pointer point past the deleted node, and to the next.

Comment: I'm aware that the code deletes the actual node, but it does delete the node that I want to ignore, because I changed ptr2 to point past the node that I delete.
I'm imagining something like this: 
ptr2 -> data1, ptr2.next
ptr2.next -> data2, ptr2.next.next
```dup = ptr2;
    ptr2 = ptr2->next;
    delete(dup);
```
 ptr2->data2, ptr2.next.next

Comment: You can set ptr1, ptr2 to anything you want. That's not going to do anything to the actual linked list nodes. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You need to change the next pointer of the node that points to the one you delete.